# Running executables from unidentified developer in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, executable, wine

I am trying to run a windows executable using wine on macOS. My command is:

```
wine64 setup.exe
```

But I keep getting an error about the executable being from an unidentified developer, which makes it impossible to run it. Wine only works in terminal, and I don't know how to supress this security measure there.

How do I disable the "unidentified developer"-check from the terminal on macOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the [spctl](https://www.manpagez.com/man/8/spctl/) tool to add it to the Gatekeeper exclusions from terminal:

`spctl --add /path/to/wine64`